# TextView not updating after change

Tags: swift, swift2, uitextview

I'm trying to edit the text in a UITextView programmatically, but the text isn't changing.

`@IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textView.delegate = self
    textView.text = messages[0]
    print(textView.text)

    }
```

`

With this simple code, I change the text of the textView. When I'm printing textView.text, it shows the right text but on screen it does nothing. The textField delegate is already set to self.

Here's an image taken in the main.storyboard

[image]

Has anyone got an idea why this is happening? This should be some really simple but I can't get it to work..

**Your Help is really appreciated! Thanks in advance**

Comment: Where are you updating the UITextView?

Comment: Apparently you can't reload it like you would with a UITableView, that's kind of my question: how to update it

Comment: This is the only code I am using..

Comment: Basically the TextView is emty and after something happens in the app, there should be some text in the textView

Comment: Yes I have done that already

Comment: Where is this code?  The initalizer? `viewDidLoad`?  We need context to those two lines of code.

Comment: @BramRoelandts try `textView.setNeedsDisplay()` after the text changing

Comment: @iamalizade doesn't work..

Comment: @Christopher I edited the question with the full code

Comment: @BramRoelandts thanks.  Okay, how was textView wired up from the interface builder?  Is it defined as an IBOutlet or did you create the UITextView programatically?

Comment: @Christopher I added an image from the storyboard. I wired it up from the interface builder

Comment: Well I'm starting to run out of ideas...  Try setting the background color of the UITextView to something distinct and put a placeholder text in.  Let's ensure that the textview is actually rendering

Comment: Thank you very much @Christopher. I found the problem! The background in the interface builder was set to black and text green, but when setting other text programmatically, the color switches back to black. I fixed it by changing textView.textColor :)

Comment: @BramRoelandts No problem.  Might be worth writing an answer explaining the solution so that anyone else with the same problem doesn't pull their hair out.

Comment: @Christopher yes indeed, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I upvoted your solution so people wouldn't have to load more comments to see the solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered by the OP in the discussion above:

Thank you very much @Christopher. I found the problem! The background in the interface builder was set to black and text green, but when setting other text programmatically, the color switches back to black. I fixed it by changing textView.textColor :)